# Proof of measurable sets and computation of measures

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

## Question

$(X, m, \mu)$ be the measure space.
Let $f: X \to [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function and assume that
$$
\int_X f\ d\mu < \infty.
$$
Let $E = \{x \in X \mid f(x) = \infty \}$.

1. Show that $E$ is a measurable set.
2. Show that $\mu(E) = 0$.

## What I know

1. Since $f$ is a measurable function and the one-point set $\{\infty\}$ is a Borel set, the following holds.
   $$
   E = f^{-1}(\{\infty\}) \in m
   $$
   Is that correct?
2. No policy is in place. Please advise.

Comment: yes $\{\infty \}$ is a Borel set, so $f^{-1}(\infty )$ is measurable because $f$ is a measurable function. By the other side I don't know what you are trying to say with "No policy is in place. Please advise."

Comment: By contradiction, assume that $\mu(E)\ne 0$. What would that imply for $\int_X f\ d\mu$ ?

Comment: Number 2 is definitely the harder part of the claim. One way to proceed is to use the following fact: $f \geq n \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{f \geq n\}}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's take from the top!

- When it comes to $1.$, your understanding is correct.
- Now, $2.$ is a little trickier, but here is the step by step:

First, notice that $\forall \; x \in X, \; f(x) \geq n \cdot \mathbb1_{\{ f \, \geq \, n \}}(x)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (To prove the inequality, we are using the fact that $f$ is nonnegative). It probably feels innocuous right now, but this is key. Also important: each set $\{ f \, \geq \, n \}$ is measurable given the measurability of $f$ (Just being explicit).
We can, now, integrate on both sides of the inequality to find that

\begin{equation*}
\infty > \int_X f \; d\mu \geq n \cdot \mu(\{ f \, \geq \, n \}).
\end{equation*}

Because the integral is finite, we can write, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$

\begin{equation*}
\mu(\{ f \, \geq \, n \}) \leq \cfrac{\int_X f \; d\mu}{n} < \infty.
\end{equation*}

The Squeeze Theorem guarantees that the limit of our sequence is zero, that is,

\begin{equation*}
lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\{ f \, \geq \, n \}) = 0.
\end{equation*}

Now, you might be wondering, "So what? This is not what I need at all." Fret not, here is how we tie everything together: Define the following sequence of sets $B_n = \{ f \geq n \}$. Then, it is a sequence of decreasing measurable sets, such that $\cap_{n = 1}^\infty B_n = \{ f = \infty \}$ (Try showing the equality is true) and, such that each element $B_n$ has finite measure. From here on, we can use monotone continuity from above, to show that

\begin{align*}
\mu(\{ f = \infty \}) & = \mu(\cap_{n = 1}^\infty B_n) \\[3pt]
& = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(B_n) \\[3pt]
& = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\{ f \, \geq \, n \}) = 0.
\end{align*}

This concludes $2.$

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, a trivial proof is as follow: suppose that $\mu(E)=c>0$, then you have that
$$
\int_{X}f\,d \mu =\int_{E}f \,d \mu +\int_{E^\complement }f\,d \mu =\mu(E)\cdot \infty +\int_{E^\complement }f\,d \mu=\infty +\int_{E^\complement }f\,d \mu=\infty 
$$
as $f$ is measurable and non-negative and so from the definition of the integral of Lebesgue we knows that $\int_{E^\complement }f\,d \mu\in[0,\infty ]$.∎

---

Another short proof: note that $f\geqslant f \cdot \mathbf{1}_{E}$ and suppose that $\mu(E)>0$, therefore as the integral is a monotone operator we have that
$$
\infty =\infty \cdot \mu(E)=\int_{X}f\cdot \mathbf{1}_{E}\,d \mu\leqslant \int_{X}f\,d \mu 
$$
∎

Comment: Wow, great proofs!